# Handling a String From a Web API Service in Object-C

Tags: objective-c, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple Web API Service POST

```
  // POST api/values
    public string Post(SimpleRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Field1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Password)) 
            return "Something is missing.";
        return string.Format("Success. You sent {0}!", request.Field1);
    }
```

Which is consumed in an a object-c method (for an iphone project):

```
- (IBAction)doSomethingButtonWasPressed:(id)sender {

    NSString * urlString = @"http://192.168.0.XXX/api/Test";
    NSDictionary *postDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              _field1.text, @"Field1",
                              _field2.text, @"Field2",
                              nil];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSData *req= [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];//
    [request setHTTPBody:req];

    NSURLResponse* response;
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"The output is:%@",responseString);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Result"
                                                    message:responseString
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

It all works, **except** the result has "quotes" around it. I feel like maybe I'm missing a decoding step?

Comment: What "result" has quotes around it? `responseString`?

Comment: Correct, yes. If I sent all of the information, the result would be "Success. You sent XYZ", and the quotes would display in the message box. If i just put a string literal in the message box, there are no quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the service is returning JSON, like {"foo"} that would appear as a quoted string.  Try interpreting the data as JSON with ...

```
NSError *error;
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:nil error:&error];
NSLog(@"result is %@, error is %@", result, error);
```

Comment: Actually, WebApi is not returning json as far as I can tell, it's just returning a quoted string.